# Connecting Tables in Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm new in creating database in Microsoft Access, I'm trying to figure out how to connect tables in it. I have 3 tables, I named it as Products, Suppliers, and Prod_Supp. In my Prod_Supp table I have fields where it is also a field in my Products and Suppliers table. What I want to do is that when I enter data in Prod_Supp it will automatically added to the same fields in products and Suppliers table. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the Prod_Supp is a link-table between Products en Suppliers for both having a n-to-n relation to each other.

In that case: there always hás to be a Supplier and a Product before you can link them together. So the Prod_Supp table has just 2 fields, and 2 fields only: a foreign key to Supplier.ID and a foreign key to Product.ID.

Automation of the addition of a Supplier or a Product by filling in the fields in the linktable is not desirable. Normally and ideally, that linktable just contains meaningless integers, so you would not know what to enter. In fact, that table doesn't need a GUI at all.